# Compile JAR file with all of its JAR dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a JAR file that I downloaded from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/authzforce/authzforce-ce-restful-pdp-cxf-spring-boot-server/1.4.0/). It turns out to run this JAR it requires several other JAR files, such as bson4jackson-2.7.0.jar  jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar.

Is that possible to compile the JAR that I downloaded with other JAR files into a single fat JAR or JAR with dependencies? Is there Maven command to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [maven shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) plugin it will create a fat jar here is an example

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>jar2</finalName>
                            <transformers>
                                <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.greg.App</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: I only have JAR file and those dependencies. In this case I should make a new Maven project?

Comment: @IhsanHaikal yes, create a new maven project add all those jars as dependencies and   maven will create a fat jar, i.e. a jar with all the classes exploded so the class loader can find them.

Comment: Ok I'll try that. But what about the mainClass attribute like what you wrote in the answer? What should I write then?

Comment: Are you trying to create a runnable jar?

Comment: Yes but I run into errors now. See my update for the pom.xml and error